# MySql AES_Encrypt to more secure algorithm

Tags: mysql, security, encryption, openssl, aes

I've some thousands of AES_ENCRYPT records. The problem is that I've just realized that ECB mode is very unsecure.

How could I turn AES_ENCRYPT 128 ECB to openssl (or others) AES 256 CBC?

Many thanks

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/aes-ecb-mode-for-single-block-random-data-encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see here](http://www.mail-archive.com/mysql@lists.mysql.com/msg73071.html)

you need to recompile it after mofiying file `include/my_aes.h`

```
#define AES_KEY_LENGTH 128 /* must be 128 192 or 256 */
```